# Java server application to emulate Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc, wireshark

I have a client Java application which connects over JDBC to MySql server. I would like to replace MySql with prototype Java server application. This application should receive and send bytes back to client over the socket, so that client „thinks“ that it communicates with Mysql.
I have done the Wireshark capture and got hex values. Now I would like to emulate, send the same Server Greeting bytes from server to client so that client starts to send sql commands to server.
This is the capture from Wireshark when Mysql responds to Java client. This is Mysql Greeting server response:

```
0000   00 19 99 5d 6f 53 00 12 00 85 4c ce 08 00 45 00  ...]oS....L...E.
0010   00 60 3e 49 40 00 3f 06 e8 84 8d 1d 7d 35 8d 1d  .`>I@.?.....}5..
0020   7d 5a 0c ea ef dc 14 56 67 8e 17 b8 70 a8 50 18  }Z.....Vg...p.P.
0030   00 73 af 71 00 00 34 00 00 00 0a 35 2e 31 2e 36  .s.q..4....5.1.6
0040   31 00 74 00 00 00 4a 29 2e 4b 6d 66 38 22 00 ff  1.t...J).Kmf8"..
0050   f7 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
0060   00 3f 56 72 5c 58 23 44 6d 76 2c 73 22 00        .?Vr\X#Dmv,s".
```

and this is another Wireshark capture, when I have my Java server which is replacement for Mysql. My Java server application emulates Mysql Server Greeting message but it sends to much bytes for some reason:

```
0000   00 19 99 5d 6f 53 00 12 00 85 4c ce 08 00 45 00  ...]oS....L...E.
0010   00 96 8d 8d 40 00 3f 06 99 0a 8d 1d 7d 35 8d 1d  ....@.?.....}5..
0020   7d 5a 0c ea fd 4b a8 2d 3f 6d 96 b3 42 b3 50 18  }Z...K.-?m..B.P.
0030   00 73 85 d7 00 00 00 19 99 5d 6f 53 00 12 00 85  .s.......]oS....
0040   4c ce 08 00 45 00 00 60 3e 49 40 00 3f 06 e8 84  L...E..`>I@.?...
0050   8d 1d 7d 35 8d 1d 7d 5a 0c ea ef dc 14 56 67 8e  ..}5..}Z.....Vg.
0060   17 b8 70 a8 50 18 00 73 af 71 00 00 34 00 00 00  ..p.P..s.q..4...
0070   0a 35 2e 31 2e 36 31 00 74 00 00 00 4a 29 2e 4b  .5.1.61.t...J).K
0080   6d 66 38 22 00 ff f7 08 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  mf8"............
0090   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 56 72 5c 58 23 44 6d 76  .......?Vr\X#Dmv
00a0   2c 73 22 00                                      ,s".
```

How can I send the same bytes that I captured with Wireshark from Java server over the socket to the Java client?
Here is the Java code I use on the server side:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Server { 

    /**
     * 
     */
    public void run() {
    try {
        int serverPort = 3306;
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(10000); 
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "..."); 

            Socket server = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println("Just connected to " + server.getRemoteSocketAddress()); 


            byte[] clientMessage = hexStringToByteArray("0019995d6f53001200854cce0800450000603e4940003f06e8848d1d7d358d1d7d5a0ceaefdc1456678e17b870a850180073af710000340000000a352e312e363100740000004a292e4b6d66382200fff7080200000000000000000000000000003f56725c5823446d762c732200");


            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            bos.write(clientMessage);   
            bos.flush();

            System.out.println("Data sent back");   

        }
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String string) {
        int len = string.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(string.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server srv = new Server();
        srv.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe port forwarding or proxy/tunneling is all you need?

Comment: Because, it is specific system, where I need to capture SQL query from clients, convert query to SPML and send it to another system which understands SPML to retrieve some data.

Comment: Stop now. ***This will never work.*** You need to find the actual MySQL wire protocol definition, if you can, and implement it properly, not just parrot what you see on Wireshark.

Comment: MySQL wire protocol docs are [available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html). Searching for "mysql java proxy" also turns this up: https://github.com/MPjct/JMPjct which you might want to take a look at.

Comment: @Miromiro, any update? I have a similar problem, did you find a working solution?

Comment: mysql2 on npm has the server side implementation, in JS